# Access static mathod before using »super«

Tags: oop, ecmascript-6

there is this class hierarchy:

```
class A {
  constructor (obj) {
    this.obj = obj
  }
}

class B extends A {

  static createObj () { 
    return {from: 'B'};
  }

  constructor () {
    const obj = B.createObj();
    super(obj);
  }
}
```

I would like to extend this such that:

```
class C extends B {
  static createObj () {
    return { from: 'C' };
  }
}

//such that:
console.log(new C().obj.from) // 'C'
```

**BUT** therefore I need to change `const obj = B.createObj()` to something like:  `const obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.createObj();`, what is throwing this error:

```
 ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
```

So basically I would like to override a method that creates an object to be used within the `super()` call. Since `this` cannot be used before that, I chose to use a static method. Is there any way to reference the static method, without using this and without overriding the constructor as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your `this.obj=obj` to be done **only** in class A for some reason, then I would do:

```
class A {
    constructor(obj) {
        this.obj = obj
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static createObj() {
        return { from: 'B' };
    }
    constructor(obj) {
        if (!obj) obj = B.createObj();
        super(obj);
    }
}

class C extends B {
    static createObj() {
        return { from: 'C' };
    }
    constructor(obj) {
        if (!obj) obj = C.createObj();
        super(obj);
    }
}

console.log(new C().obj.from)
```

Output:

```
"C"
```

But in my opinion the best OOP approach would be this:

```
class A {
    constructor(obj) {
        this.obj = obj
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static createObj() {
        return { from: 'B' };
    }
    constructor(obj) {
        super(obj);
        this.obj = B.createObj();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    static createObj() {
        return { from: 'C' };
    }
    constructor(obj) {
        super(obj);
        this.obj = C.createObj();
    }
}
console.log(new C().obj.from)
```

Output:

```
"C"
```

The 2nd approach allows to satisfy the pattern "call super before doing anything else" that can prevent bugs.

It's up to you to chose which one better suits your needs, but both prints "C" without requiring `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.createObj()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am searching for a way where I just have to override one method, to modify the creation of `obj`. Each of your suggested way implies to override too methods…

Comment: If you want to override only createObj, it means you can't override the constructor. And this means the constructor of C will be the constructor of B. This means from constructor of B (parent class) you would like to call C.createObj in the child class (not directly, using getPrototypeOf(this), I got this, but anyway that's what it will do). It's really a twisted and discouraged OOP pattern. Why would you want to override only 1 method in the first place? Is it an homework assignment or something? Because other than technical proof of concept for research, it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: »It's really a twisted and discouraged OOP pattern« — could you please provide any more information on this, a link or alike? Basically the thing I am doing here is using the decorator pattern and `obj` refers to the »component«. I am just looking for a simple/short way to tweak the component…